# Multiple NSStrings in Conditional Statement

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I need a bit of guidance with his - I want textField1 to display "Unsupported ..." if anything *other than* files with the extension strings in the code below are dragged into the application. No problem with drag and drop.

Am I off track? Can't get it to work ...

thx.

```
if (![extension isEqualToString:@"moef"] || (![extension isEqualToString:@"motn"] || (![extension isEqualToString:@"moti"] || (![extension isEqualToString:@"motr"])))){

    [textField1 setStringValue:@"Unsupported ..."];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying right now is this: 'If the extension isn't x, or it isn't y, or it isn't z, or it isn't a, do this'. Here's the thing: Since an extension can't be all four at once, your condition will always trigger.

What you want to say instead is 'if the extension isn't x, y, z, or a, do this. It sounds the same, but the difference is there if you think about it for a while. This code should work:

```
if (!([extension isEqualToString:@"moef"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"motn"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"moti"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"motr"]))
{
    [textField1 setStringValue:@"Unsupported ..."];
}
```